# express js route cache clear (heroku)

Tags: express, heroku, caching, routes, pug

I am using `express js` and added new .pug file and given the link in `routes/index.js`

But when I try to access in the browser url, it is redirected to (404 page not found)

Can I know how to clear the routes cache. In my previous nodejs app it has pm2, so I restarted that. But here no pm2, I don't know what to do?. Any help would be much appreciated.

***Note: I have tried this [link](https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) but does not works.***

**EDIT**

routes/index.js

```
// set up dependencies
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
//
//
// Home Page
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('home', {
    meta : {
      title: 'Home'
    }
  })
});
//
//
// About Page
router.get('/about', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('about', {
    meta : {
      title: 'About Us'
    }
  })
});
//
//
//Partners Page
router.get('/partners', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('partners', {
    meta : {
      title: 'Partners'
    }
  })
});

//
//
// export the module
module.exports = router;
```

/app.js

```
// import dependencies
var express = require('express'), // Used for routing https://expressjs.com/
path = require('path'), // allows path combinations https://www.npmjs.com/package/path
favicon = require('serve-favicon'), // serves the favicon from spec. folder https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-favicon
logger = require('morgan'), // logs errors and output to terminal during node run https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'), // allows cookie parsing https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser
bodyParser = require('body-parser'), // allos parsing of req.body in POST requests https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser
session = require('express-session'), // express session storage... just using in-memory sessions https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session
pug = require('pug'), // pug/jade templating language https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug
timeout = require('connect-timeout'), // sets the timeout on the app before we show error https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeout
compression = require('compression'), // gzip compression for nodejs https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression
port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// import local dependencies
require('dotenv').config(); // loads CONFIG variables from the .env top-level file

// app internal setup
var app = express(); // sets app to use express
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); // sets up view directory
app.set('view engine', 'pug'); // sets view engine to use pug
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'images', 'icons', 'favicon.ico'))); // sets favicon path
app.use(logger('dev')); // uses morgan/logger to log output to terminal
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // uses bodyParser to parse req
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true })); // Parses the text as URL encoded data, extended extends UTF chars
app.use(cookieParser('secret')); // sets the session secret
// set up session storage (we dont really need this for this app, no login)
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // sets static file directory path
app.use(compression()); // uses compression
app.use(timeout('100s')); // sets timeout interval

// set up routing
var routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);

// error catching
// stacktrace in dev., dislay error page in prod
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.render('error', { 
      meta : {
        title: '404 Page Not Found'
      }
    })
  });
}
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
  res.status(err.status || 404);
  // log the error for heroku logs
  console.log('error', err);
  res.render('error', {});
});

// serve the app on PORT variable
// if using Heroku, this will be automatically set
var server = app.listen(port, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('App listening error ', err);
  } else {
    console.log('App running at ', port)
  }
});
```

App file structure

```
app
|_ .heroku
|_ .profile.d
|_ node_modules
|_ public
|_ routes
 |_ index.js
|_ views
 |_ home.pug
 |_ about.pug
 |_ partners.pug
|_ .gitignore
|_ app.js
|_ gulpfile.js
|_ package-lock.json
|_ package.json
|_ Procfile
|_ README.md
|_ service-worker.js
```

Comment: Try to show us some codes so we can help you better.

Comment: @AvivLo Thanks for your response. I have edited the question with my code. Please look into it.

Comment: @AvivLo Previously I had Home, About page. Now newly added partners page. When I try to access my partners page, it shows 404 error. I have created the partners.pug file in my views directory.

Comment: Does the other page work.

Comment: @AvivLo Yes, those were done by other unknown persons. only new pages not working. showing 404 error page.

Comment: Does it work locally though?

Comment: @AvivLo No. I have tested in devlopment(local) and in staging(online) both same 404 error.

Comment: May you show us the file structure of your views

Comment: @AvivLo Please check my edited question

Comment: I mean it looks totally fine. Could you test it locally again and see if it works?

Comment: @AvivLo will check and let you know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212473/discussion-between-droiddev-and-aviv-lo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my friend debugged the code and found that error is in the `partners.pug` file. Spacing problem. So I copied another pug file and renamed as `partners.pug` and linked in the `routes/index.js` it then worked. It may help someone.